# Stuck between upgrade versions -- Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I am stuck between version 10.04 and 10.10 of Ubuntu .  I started upgrading when the computer cashed; now I can not boot back to the hard drive.  I am currently up on a live 10.10 cd.  How can I proceed?

As a side note I would prefer not having to reformat the hard drive as for I have a few files that I need to affirm that I have backups of.

Comment: In such situation Fresh Install would be better option and Back up your few files to cloud ( if no other  storage ) from live cd if possible .And try 12.04 for fresh install .

Answer (score 1):

You might try dropping into a shell and chrooting to rescue the installation.  Here's a link: http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/

You could boot into a rescue shell, or use the CD.  If you use the CD, make sure you mount all your partitions.  Then open a terminal and chroot to your installation:
ie, type (replace with appropriate path):

```
chroot [pathtoMountedInstallation] /bin/bash
```

That will change the terminal to think that your installation is the root.  Then you can:

```
sudo dpkg --configure
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hopefully that will work, but it may depend on when the upgrade failed.